# Custom fusion table maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, iframe

I have a number of fusion tables, each of which can be viewed in the form of maps. There iframe representation is along the following lines:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&amp;q=select+col0+from+1w5Ksc0GqzFKgf91tyauCbnhymszbsNlQay8scLs&amp;h=false&amp;lat=58.3&amp;lng=19.1&amp;z=11&amp;t=1&amp;l=col0"></iframe>
```

How I use javascript to replace the src so as to switch between maps?

How can I use a search box so as to center the map based on a user inputted address?

Answer (score 0):

if the iframe had an ID you would just take the new src and replace it...

`$('#iframeIDwhateveritis').attr('src', 'newhttpSrchere');`

The search box thing you'd have to look up the documentation on whatever maps you are using...